# How to use internet on a Wi-Fi only iPad in a residence with no Wi-Fi?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, skype, ipad

I want to speak on Skype on my Wi-Fi-only iPad Air iOS 7 from my residence. However, the people tending the residence don't want to install Wi-Fi. There are only ethernet cables. Here's what I've considered:

1. Getting ethernet directly on my iPad (as explained [here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/08/28/how-to-connect-an-ipad-to-ethernet/))

   This is not practical, because ethernet cables are in public rooms at my residence. If I spoke on Skype there, I would disturb everyone else in the room.
2. Sharing my phone's data plan to my iPad

   This would probably get expensive way too fast.

I have a Sony Vaio laptop, but the fan makes a lot of noise, and Skype conversations are impossible.

Currently, whenever I want to speak on Skype, I have to go to a group study room at the university's library. This means that I have to cope with the library's tight opening hours and a very small room that renders poor audio to whomever I speak with.

How can I get some internet on my iPad Air in a private room of my residence with no Wi-Fi or ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1):

Just buy a cheap router, connect it to one of the ethernet cables in your room, and enable wi-fi.

Comment: Or use internet sharing on the laptop you have

Answer (score 0):

Apple USB camera connector adapters also work to plug in many USB to ethernet adapters. You can connect just about any recent lightning and USB-C device from Apple to a [network with third party ethernet adapters and skip WiFi entirely.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411291/5472)

You’ll want another solution for devices that use the 30-pin connectors.