# USB C to Ethernet on iPad Air 4 in hotel

Tags: ipad, network, ethernet, ipados

The WiFi in my hotel room has been dropping video calls so I got a USB C to ethernet adapter and plugged it into my iPad Air 4 running the latest iOS. Ethernet settings appear in the settings app and show an IP address but nothing will connect to the internet.

Apple Support was at a loss so I called the hotel’s internet provider and the agent said she could authorize my device for internet. Great. But she needed a specific address from my iPad. She said it’s a USB key. I have no idea what this means or where to find it in iOS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting good advice and the hotel probably needs the hardware [media access control address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) which is like a serial number on the adapter. If you can’t find that out from a computer, manufacturer support, the labeling on the part or the box, ask if you can use a web browser to navigate to http://captive.apple.com to register.

You can also ask them if setting the DHCP client ID or address manually works. You can’t discover the ethernet MAC address from iOS 14 (afaik) - here is what you can see and control in the settings app if you tap Ethernet.

[image: iOS 14 settings for ethernet USB-C adapter]

For WiFi and Bluetooth you can see these addresses on iPhone and iPad  (like 16:00:DD:EE:FF:78 ) and even specify a private one different than the factory address, but this doesn’t apply to ethernet adapters currently.